# How to source env variables in Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, reactjs

I have a node/react project in Windows.

And an env variables file that looks like this:

```
export GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=UA-XXXXXX-XX
export GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID=GTM-XXXXX
export MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=aaabbbb
export MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID=ccccdddd
```

How can I source it in that project?
What should the file be called and what command should I run?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can cross platform tools to set env variables:

- https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

But you will have to remove all `export` calls from your file:

**.env**

```
GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=UA-XXXXXX-XX
GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID=GTM-XXXXX
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=aaabbbb
MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID=ccccdddd
```

And use it in package.json with `env-cmd`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd .env node server.js"
  }
}
```

In order to preserve existing functionality for linux you can create separate file with variables and in original file wirte something like:

**.env-params**

```
GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID=UA-XXXXXX-XX
GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER_ID=GTM-XXXXX
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=aaabbbb
MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID=ccccdddd
```

**.env**

```
set -o allexport
source .env-params
set +o allexport
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd .env-params node server.js"
  }
}
```

And use it as before `source .env` and ``